# Set system ENV with the shell file inside the container

Tags: bash, shell, docker

Try to set System ENV with the shell script when run the container, the problem is when I see the logs, the "**printenv**" shows me that the "**MYENV=123**" but when I echo it inside the container is empty.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

ADD first.sh /opt/first.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/first.sh

ADD second.sh /opt/second.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/second.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/first.sh" ]
```

first.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/second.sh
printenv

tail -f /dev/null
```

second.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

BLA=`echo blabla 123 | sed 's/blabla //g'`
echo "${BLA}"

export MYENV=${BLA}
```

I don't want to use docker env in a run or with docker-compose, because this workflow will help me to change the **env** when I'm running the container

Answer (score 0):

The technique you've described will work fine.  I'd write it slightly differently:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /opt/second.sh
exec "$@"
```

This will set environment variables for the main process in your container (and not ignore the `CMD` or anything you set on the command line).  It won't affect any other shells you happen to launch with `docker exec`: they don't run as children of the container's main process and won't have "seen" these environment variable settings.

This technique won't make it particularly easier or harder to change environment variables in your container.  Since the only way one process's environment can affect another's is by providing the initial environment when it starts up, even if you edit the `second.sh` in the live container (not generally a best practice) it won't affect the main process's environment (in your case, the `tail` command).  This is one of a number of common situations where you need to at least restart the container to make changes take effect.

Comment: how does it work for you? 1.build the image(you see in the logs it prints the ENV 2.go inside the container echo the ENV and it is empty. Also used _exec "$@"_ but still print an empty env.

Comment: If I `docker run ... sh` I will see the environment variable.  If I use `CMD` to set up the container's main process it will have variable set in its environment.

Comment: I found the work around for that, but is not clean in my opinion which is echo the result to the .bashrc _echo "MYENV=${BLA}" >> ~/.bashrc_

Comment: Try _docker run -d myImage sh_ then run _exec_ not anymore available